# C#. After 5 failed attempts are reached, the message "You have run out of guesses! It was number " + number is never displayed, I need help. Thanks

Tags: c#, message, display

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int guess;
        public static void DisplayMessage(string message)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(message);       
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            var number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
            DisplayMessage("Try and guess any number between 1 - 100.You have 5 guesses Max!");

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int guess);
                if (guess == number)
                {
                    DisplayMessage("You got it!");
                }
                else if (guess != number)
                {
                    DisplayMessage(guess + " is not correct! Try again!");
                }

                else if (guess != number && counter == 5)
                {
                    DisplayMessage("You have run out of guesses! It was number " + number);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if` excludes other clauses, so you need to nest `if(counter == 5)` inside an `else`

Comment: You need to write text in the body of your question, not just the title.  Explain what you tried, what you expect and what actually happened in the question body.  Explain to us what your level of understanding of the situation is.  People will also expect that you have done some basic debugging on your own and understand the flow of your program and reasons for the conditionals having the values they do.

Comment: Thank you Charlieface. It worked!!

Comment: Mr Wyck, I am new in this world of Programming, sorry. Next time I will be more explanatory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You're just missing an **and** in the first `else if` plus you forgot to increase the counter:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    int counter = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    var number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
    Console.WriteLine("Try and guess any number between 1 - 100.You have 5 guesses Max!");

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        counter++; //forgot this
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int guess);
        if (guess == number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
        }
        else if (guess != number && counter != 5) //added one more condition here
        {
            Console.WriteLine(guess + " is not correct! Try again!");
        }

        else if (guess != number && counter == 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have run out of guesses! It was number " + number);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked!